# Implementing protocols in user space versus kernel space - performance implication

Tags: performance, tcp

I am looking for some articles / papers on the impact of moving a protocol implementation say TCP/IP stack from kernel to user space. It will obviously have an impact but how much? Or there is any literature of how much the context switch costs. I realize that there may not be an accurate answers because it will depend on the application. Assuming therefore it is a network stack, it will be great if anyonce can probvide some inputs. I googled but cannot find anything good except this [User space Vs Kernel space program performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272478/user-space-vs-kernel-space-program-performance-difference)
but which does not shed enough light.

Comment: The question as it stands is off-topic for SO, since you are asking for an off-site resource rather than an answer to a programming question. AFAIK, TCP stack in user space can perform better than in kernel space so long as the application on top of the stack is in the same process as the stack itself. If you want a "micro-kernel" type architecture where the stack is its own process, you will pay for another context switch, so some kind of efficient batch notification system would need to be designed.

Comment: Well, there must be something worthwhile about it for folks like Solarflare/Mellanox to produce cards and stacks that by-pass the kernel and run pretty much entirely in user space (as long as it's in your process.) But, I'd imagine without some hardware support, these things are notoriously hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you could see for file system comparisions - there is many different implementations, as kernel modules and as fuse modules.
May be you can find interesting information in this types of components.

Also in field of network I can mention that some drivers utilize ability of network cards to calc hash's for ethernet frames - and there is some gane of it. 
If you work on user space - you can't use such trick.
In result you can get compassions of performance in use of such trick as upper bound of performance penalty.